# Make Docker use / load a .tar image without copying it to /var/lib/..?

Tags: docker

I am aware you can export a docker container/image as a .tar file, then use docker load on another system to import it. The problem is docker load places the image into /var/lib/.. and the host system has very little space. Is there a way to have docker run the image directly from the tar file, or use the working dir of the file location?

Otherwise the only resort is symlinks to trick docker?

Comment: Usually you mount a separate volume for `/var/lib/docker` to get some isolation between your root filesystem and all the docker layers.

Comment: any idea if docker will pick up images that just "appear" there, without doing a proper load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `docker load`, you need at least:

- Enough space to hold the original tar file; and
- Enough space to hold the uncompressed tar file in `/var/lib/docker/tmp`; and
- Enough space to hold the image contents in the Docker image space.

The actual format of the image contents is different from the contents of the tar file and is installation-specific (devicemapper vs. aufs vs. overlay2 installations will look different).  There's no way to bypass this and directly "inject" a tar file.

If disk space is really tight, I think setting up a Docker registry and using `docker pull` instead will require less space (my immediate guess would be the size of the image plus the size of the single largest layer), and will generally be easier to manage.

If the system is a cloud-hosted system with an unfortunately small default root disk, consider destroying the current instance and provisioning a new one with enough storage.

Comment: unfortunate, only original plan left to mount / symlink /var/lib/docker :(, hopefully it can find the images if they just "appear" there, instead of having to have it recopy everything.