# Error when uploading my Docker image to my AWS EC2 instance: "no space left on device" when there is space left

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to upload my Docker image to my AWS EC2 instance. I uploaded a gunzipped version, unzipped the file and am trying to load the image with the following command `docker image load -i /tmp/harrybotter.tar` and encountering the following error:

`Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: no space left on device`

Except, there is plenty of space on the instance, it's brand new, nothing is on it. Docker says the image is only 2.25 GB and the entire instance has 8 GiB of storage space. I have nothing else uploaded to the instance so the storage space is largely free. Every time the upload fails the upload is always at 2.1 GB or so.

Running `df -h`  before the upload returns

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        475M     0  475M   0% /dev
tmpfs           483M     0  483M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           483M  420K  483M   1% /run
tmpfs           483M     0  483M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  4.2G  3.9G  53% /
tmpfs            97M     0   97M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I am completely new to docker and AWS instances, so I am at a loss for what to do other than possibly upgrading my EC2 instance above the free tier. But since the instance has additional storage space, I am confused why the upload is running out of storage space. Is there a way I can expand the docker base image size or change the path the image is being uploaded to?

Thanks!

Comment: It won't solve your problem (and it's not a programming-related problem, so not really on topic for Stack Overflow) but you might consider using a Docker registry, possibly ECR, instead of manually `docker load`ing images; it's more in line with standard Docker procedure and easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned image size is 2.25 GB on loading image it required more space.
Check this out: [Make Docker use / load a .tar image without copying it to /var/lib/..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55111969/make-docker-use-load-a-tar-image-without-copying-it-to-var-lib)